# Using map on dataset with arbitrary rows in Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use the Dataframe map function on an arbitrary dataset. However I don't understand how you would map from Row-> Row. No examples are given for arbitrary data in the spark sql documentation:

```
Dataset<Row> original_data = ...
Dataset<Row> changed_data = original_data.map(new MapFunction<Row,Row>{
            @Override
            public Row call(Row row) throws Exception {
                Row newRow = RowFactory.create(obj1,obj2);
                return newRow;
            }
}, Encoders.bean(Row.class));
```

However this does not work since there needs to be some sort of Encoder?
How can I map to a generic Row?

Comment: what's type of obj1 and obj2? is it primitive datatype?

Comment: Map is more a RDD function, with Spark SQL you should try to use "select" and "with column" ... And if you have the chance, you should try to code this in Scala, its way easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If obj1 and and obj2 are not primitive type then represent their schema to StructType to create Row encoder. I would suggest instead of using Row type, create custom bean which stores both obj1 and obj2 then use that custom bean encoder in `map` transformation.

**Row type:**

```
StructType customStructType = new StructType();
        customStructType = customStructType.add("obj1", DataTypes.< type>, false);
        customStructType = customStructType.add("obj2", DataTypes.< type >, false);
        ExpressionEncoder<Row> customTypeEncoder = null;

        Dataset<Row> changed_data = original_data.map(row->{
            return RowFactory.create(obj1,obj2);;
    }, RowEncoder.apply(customStructType));
```

**Custom Bean type:**

```
class CustomBean implements ....{
    Object obj1;
    Object obj2;
....
}

Dataset<CustomBean> changed_data = original_data.map(row->{
                return new CustomBean(obj1,obj2);
        }, Encoders.bean(CustomBean));
```